# How to allow parameter to pass blank entry and comma separated multi entry?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I have inherited some code for a query to build a report off of, with a parameter that needs to be able to be left blank and return all rows, take one value and return the value of just that row, and take in multiple values and return all the rows where that value appears.

I am able to set up the query the report is running off of so that I can leave the parameter and blank and return all rows and enter one value and return that one row, or enter one value and return one row and enter multiple comma separated values and return multiple rows, but not both at the same time.

So the code for the relevant part of the query is

```
create table example as

'~' || (replace(replace(@ParamterNumber, ',' '~'), ' '~)) || '~' as 
ParameterNumber;

select * from database d

where (select ParameterNumber from example) like '%' || d.checknumber || '%';

drop table example if exists;
```

From that, when I enter, for example, '123, 456' as the parameter, it will return the rows where the value is 123, and rows where the value is 456. Similarly, if the parameter is just '123', it returns rows where the value is 123. If the parameter is left blank, it returns no rows. Normally, if I wanted a blank parameter to return all rows, I would have

```
where d.checknumber like '%' || @ParameterNumber || '%'
```

, but that won't allow for multiple entries. I'm not sure how to reconcile the two into the same query so that all three conditions (blank, one entry, and multiple entries) can be satisfied.

Comment: for posterity's sake, a solution was quite simple; just combining them in an or statement
    
    (((select ParameterNumber from example) like '%' || d.checknumber || '%'
   
     or 
    
    d.checknumber like '%' || (select ParameterNumber from example) || '%')

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I can explain the process on how you can achieve that, but not sure If I will be able to write the query very well.

In your procedure which SSRS is using.Using Split string function (if you have) will allow for multiple selection and isnull and nullif condition will make sure that you are getting default value 'Blank' for case where you have nulls or blanks.

```
where isnull(nullif(d.checknumber,''),'Blank')  in (select value from split_string(@ParameterNumber,',')
```

Then go to your report builder, and while setting up parameters for @ParameterNumber you need to give in this way.

```
select distinct isnull(nullif(d.checknumber,''),'Blank') ParameterNumber from Yourtablename
```

give where condition if you want cascading features. This will help you in doing multi select plus blank values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use coalesce function in SSRS as  below

```
select * from database d where  d.checknumber like coalesce(Parameter, product)
```

coalesce  docs link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#comparing-coalesce-and-case)